# how traduce [0.] from python to r

Tags: python, r

I'm doing some script from *Nishant Shukla-Machine Learning with TensorFlow* and I don't know how convert this row in R:

```
y_dataset_params = [0.] * num_coeffs
```

I don't know what is the value [0.].

Any help? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

In Python:

- `0.` is the value 0 in the data type float.
- `[0.]` is a list of one float zero.
- `[0.] * n` is a list of n float zero’s.

In R you can do `numeric(n)` to init a list of n zero’s.

Comment: Yes. Using rep is practically the same. Numeric is (AFAIK) slightly faster, but that’s peanuts.

Comment: If you’re happy with the answer, could you accept it as such?

Answer (score 0):

`[0.]` is a list with only one value, the float `0.`. In python you can multiply a list by an integer n to create a list with n copies of the initial list. So here `y_dataset_params` will be a list of `num_coeffs` zeros.